# unable to download json data too large in swift

Tags: ios, json, swift

I tried downloading data to JSON from a webserver that accepts username and password input in a json format. Once I have authenticated, I have to download json data. So I used this method

```
let postString = ["user":"user1", "pwd": "pass1"]
        var request = URLRequest(url:URL(string:"http://vdctest.agrishare.com/list_up")!)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
        request.addValue("application-idValue", forHTTPHeaderField: "secret-key")
        request.httpBody = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: postString, options:.prettyPrinted)
        let session = URLSession.shared
        //Post
        session.dataTask(with: request){data, response, err in
            //Guard: ws there error ?
            guard(err == nil) else {
                print("err")
                return
            }
            //Guard: check was any data returned?
            guard let data = data else{
                print("no data return")
                return
            }
            //Convert Json to Object
            let parseResult: [String:AnyObject]!
            do{
                parseResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options:.allowFragments) as! [String:AnyObject]
                print("\(parseResult)")
            } catch {
                print("Could not parse data as Json \(data)")
                return
            }
            //Check jsonDictionary
            guard let jsonArray = parseResult["success"] as? [String:AnyObject] else{
                print("jsonDictionary error")
                return
            }
            //check jsonArray and switch to LoginViewController
            if(jsonArray.count == 0 ){
                print("jsonArray not found")
                return
            } else{
                DispatchQueue.main.async{
                    let loginvc = LoginViewController()
                    self.present(loginvc, animated: true, completion: nil)
                    print(jsonArray)

                }
            }

            }.resume()

    }
```

When I run the app, the terminal says:

> Could not parse data as Json 1520 bytes

Why?

Output:

> Could not parse data as Json: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain
>   Code=3840 "Invalid value around character 0."
>   UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Invalid value around character 0.}

Comment: Change `print("Could not parse data as Json \(data)")` to `print("Could not parse data as Json: \(error)")` and update your question with the output.

Comment: You are not getting back JSON. Convert `data` to a `String` and have a look at it.

Comment: @rmaddy how?! 

Comment: `let resultString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)`. Note that may be `nil` which either means the string is using a different encoding or the data does't represent text.

Comment: @rmaddy ok, i've write: let resultString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
                    print(resultString) but the result is the same, `Could not parse data as Json: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Invalid value around character 0." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Invalid value around character 0.}`
'

Comment: You need to print `resultString`. This is not going to fix the problem. It's going to help you debug the problem. What is the output of `print(resultString)`?

Comment: What does this have to do with "too large"???

Comment: @rmaddy i've printed `resultString` with `print(resultString)` but nothing has changed in console 

Comment: You printed it to _yourself_ but you didn't show _us_ what it is. Do you want help or not?

Comment: Where did you add that `print`? Add it inside the `catch` block but before the `return`.

Comment: @rmaddy i have write `let resultString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)` and `print(resultString!)` inside the `catch` block and before the `return` but the console does not print anything!

Comment: @rmaddy https://pastebin.com/22KZYf9B

Comment: You do realize that everything starting with "<h1>500..." is the output of printing `resultString`, right?

Comment: @rmaddy right..and now?

Comment: Well, now you know why you can't parse the JSON. You aren't getting any JSON, you are getting an error from the server. Read that result and fix your request so it doesn't result in the server returning an error. Or contact the server developers and have them fix the problem at their end.

Comment: But does this mean I'm wrong in doing JSON parsing or are there problems with the webserver?

Comment: Arghhh! It means you are getting an error, not valid JSON. rmaddy said that (more than once.) You need to go figure out why you are getting an error and debug that.

Answer (score 1):

You likely do not have valid JSON -- as the error states, right around the very first character. Valid JSON is going to either be a single Object that opens and closes with a `{` and `}` or an Array of Objects, opening and closing with a `[` and `]`.

Please post a bit of the returned JSON to confirm.

EDIT: Also -- if you are requesting an `http` resource, and not `https`, you need to add the server to the allowed unsecure servers list.

Comment: @Taprolano I mean the JSON data returned from the request may be invalid. If you log print `data` in the handler, it should give you an idea of what the data looks like.

Comment: how to print data in the handler? print(data)?

Comment: I have printed data with `print(data)` but nothing has changed in console

Comment: @Taprolano Ahh, nm -- that just print the NSData size. `print(String(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8))` should render the data to a printable string.

Comment: Well, there you go -- it's the data of a big old error response page -- not JSON data at all. @Taprolano

Comment: But does this mean I'm wrong in doing JSON parsing or are there problems with the webserver?

Comment: @Taprolano There is definitely a problem with your server. The first bit of the data returned says `<h1>500 Internal Server Error</h1><h3>oci_connect(): ORA-28000: the account is locked (2)</h3><pre>#0 [internal function]: flight\Engine->handleError(2, 'oci_connect(): ...', '/usr/local/vdc/...', 30, Array)`. This is not JSON.